# What should be in the Windows Defender, Diagnostics folder in the registry?

Tags: windows-10, security, windows-registry, anti-virus, windows-defender

How many entries should there be?

One Windows 10 PC has 6 entries, another has 3, in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft Defender\Diagnostics.

Examples, from one machine:-

```
RollbackToPlatformVersion  REG_BINARY  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 

RolledbackPlatformHealthData  REG_SZ  <OVERALL>:<BAD>,<AGE>:<14>,<DIRTY_SHUTDOWNS>:<5>
```

Could the difference be to do with Windows Defender Offline scan, I believe that has only been run on the machine with the above entries?

Comment: I never heard anyone needing to know this. What are you trying to do? and What difference does it make?

Comment: @John It reads like the Windows Defender platform could have rolled back, however the Event ID's 1150 and 1151 for Defender say the same platform number since the last Defender platform update. Which brings the question of what should be in this directory, and why they are different. The machine with the extra entries reports some of these, on or shortly after startup, as 5007 events, like the 2nd one in the above example.

Comment: I do not know. WD could roll back if it could not finish something, but then just restart and it would likely carry on. As noted otherwise I do not know.

Comment: I did an Offline Scan on my Insider machine just to see. No such key as you post. There is data at HKLM....\Microsoft\Windows Defender\Diagnostics but not what you posted (Last Known Good and Performance Health).  So either the WD Scan went bad (as I posted earlier) or the keys are not related to WD.

Comment: Do you have another AV installed?

Comment: @John Thanks for trying that, thats interesting. The 3 keys on one PC are: Last Known Good Engine Candidate, Last Known Good Platform Location, Platform Health Data. The other PC has the first and last of those, and Platform Rollback Method, Rollback To Platform Version, Rolled Back Platform Health Data, and Rolled Back Platform Version. I did not know the keys could be regarding another program.

Comment: @John I don't have another AV. Malwarebytes is installed, but not set to start with Windows.